# nls() function in R not fitting well when calculating Kd

Tags: r, lm, nls

I'm trying to calculate Kd with the following R code but my model is clearly wrong (see image). How has `nls()` converged so poorly? How can I use it to find a better fit for my data? Why does `lm()` work so much better?

```
# log plot
plot(log10(binding_data$ligand_uM),binding_data$fraction_bound)

# 1.2   2.5   5.2  10.5  21.1  42.1  73.2 111.3 185.5 256.9 325.7 392.0
binding_data$ligand_uM

# 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.15 0.42 0.80 0.97 1.00 1.01 0.99
binding_data$fraction_bound

L  <- binding_data$ligand_uM
Kd.init.guess <- 60
Fb  <- binding_data$fraction_bound

# fitting equation
nonlinear_model2 <- nls(Fb ~ (1 / (Kd/L + 1)), start = c(Kd = Kd.init.guess),model = TRUE,trace=TRUE)

#Formula: Fb ~ (1/(Kd/L + 1))
#Parameters:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
#Kd    62.82      18.22   3.447  0.00546 **
nonlinear_model2 %>% summary()

# plot nonlinear model
lines(log10(binding_data$ligand_uM),predict(nonlinear_model2))

# half_max = 0.505
half_max <- max(binding_data$fraction_bound) / 2
half_max_r <- round(half_max,digits = 3)

# log10 Kd for plotting
Kd <- nonlinear_model2 %>% summary() %>% coefficients() %>% .[1]
Kd_r <- round(Kd,digits = 3)
log10Kd_r <- round(log10(Kd),3)

abline(h=half_max)
abline(v=log10Kd_r)

text(x=log10(Kd) - .6,y=half_max + .06,labels = paste((",log10Kd_r,",",half_max_r,")",sep=""))
title(paste("Half-Max = ",half_max_r,", Kd = 10^",log10Kd_r," = ",Kd_r,sep=""))
```

[image: nls_kd]

My fit looks better when I use `lm()` with a 4th degree polynomial (below), but I want to use the equation for Kd, rather than a 4th degree poly... I don't understand why the `nls()` approach fails and `lm()` succeeds.

```
# 1.2   2.5   5.2  10.5  21.1  42.1  73.2 111.3 185.5 256.9 325.7 392.0
binding_data$ligand_uM

# 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.15 0.42 0.80 0.97 1.00 1.01 0.99
binding_data$fraction_bound

# log plot
plot(log10(binding_data$ligand_uM),binding_data$fraction_bound)

# create model of the form Y = (1)x + (2)x^2 + (3)x^3 + (4)x^4 + (Intercept)
nonlinear_model <- lm(binding_data$fraction_bound ~ poly(log10(binding_data$ligand_uM),4,raw=TRUE))

# (1) = 1.35028
# (2) = -2.81397
# (3) = 1.90015
# (4) = -0.36699
# (Intercept) = -0.11813
# Adjusted R-squared:  0.9744
nonlinear_model %>% summary()

# plot nonlinear model
lines(log10(binding_data$ligand_uM),predict(nonlinear_model))

# half_max = 
half_max <- max(binding_data$fraction_bound) / 2
half_max_r <- round(half_max,digits = 3)

# 0.505 = -0.1181305 + 1.3502812*x - 2.8139697*x^2 + 1.9001524*x^3 - 0.3669943*x^4 
library(polynom)
pnom <- polynomial(nonlinear_model$coefficients)
pnom

# 0.2012695-0.5215514i 0.2012695+0.5215514i 1.8704424+0.0000000i 2.9046256+0.0000000i
solve(pnom,b=half_max)

# unlog Kd
log10Kd_r <- (1.8704424+0i)
Kd <- 10^log10Kd_r
Kd_r <- round(Kd,digits = 3)

abline(h=half_max)
abline(v=log10Kd_r)

text(x=log10(Kd) + .6,y=half_max + .06,labels = paste("(",log10Kd_r,",",half_max_r,")",sep=""))
title(paste("Half-Max = ",half_max_r,", Kd = 10^",log10Kd_r," = ",Kd_r,sep=""))
```

[image: lm_Kd]

Comment: A lot seems to be missing from this post: What is your first model?  Where is the `lm` model?  Note that even a fourth-degree polynomial is going to be a poor fit: it cannot accommodate the sequence of near-zero values.

Comment: I formatted the original post incorrectly.. showing all relevant code now

Comment: I'm not sure which model method to use here, but your log plot looks like a normal curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [Eldioo](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/150320/eldioo) and [Roland](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11849/roland), I was able to search around and figure this out. The solution was to use the [Hill equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_equation_(biochemistry)) "Fb ~ (1 / ((Ka/L)^n + 1))" to fit this data, rather than the [Michaelis–Menten equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics). I believe this suggests my data may represent a reaction with more than one substrate.

```
# 1.2   2.5   5.2  10.5  21.1  42.1  73.2 111.3 185.5 256.9 325.7 392.0
binding_data$ligand_uM

# 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.15 0.42 0.80 0.97 1.00 1.01 0.99
binding_data$fraction_bound

L  <- binding_data$ligand_uM
Ka.init.guess <- 60
n.init.guess <- 1
Fb  <- binding_data$fraction_bound

# fitting equation
nonlinear_model2 <- nls(Fb ~ (1 / ((Ka/L)^n + 1)), start = c(Ka = Ka.init.guess,n = n.init.guess),model = TRUE,trace=TRUE)

#Formula: Fb ~ (1/((Ka/L)^n + 1))
#Parameters:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#Ka  77.1000     1.7494   44.07 8.69e-13 ***
#n    3.4398     0.2516   13.67 8.50e-08 ***
nonlinear_model2 %>% summary()

# plot nonlinear model
lines(log10(binding_data$ligand_uM),predict(nonlinear_model2))

# half_max = 0.505
half_max <- max(binding_data$fraction_bound) / 2
half_max_r <- round(half_max,digits = 3)

# log10 Ka for plotting
Ka <- nonlinear_model2 %>% summary() %>% coefficients() %>% .[1]
Ka_r <- round(Ka,digits = 3)
log10Ka_r <- round(log10(Ka),3)

n <- nonlinear_model2 %>% summary() %>% coefficients() %>% .[2]

abline(h=half_max)
abline(v=log10Ka_r)

text(x=log10(Ka) - .6,y=half_max + .06,labels = paste("(",log10Ka_r,",",half_max_r,")",sep=""))
title(paste("Half-Max = ",half_max_r,", Ka = 10^",log10Ka_r," = ",Ka_r,sep=""))
```

[image: nls_Ka]

Answer (score 1):

Your nls estimation performs poorly, because the model formula is bad. Obviously, the shape doesn't fit the curve of the data. Therefore even the LS-optimal parameter KD can't give a good estimate.

A more fitting formula might be

```
 Fb ~ 1/(Kd/L + 1)^pow
```

as this formula accounts better for the steeper incline of the data, when the power is higher than $1$. That should give you a much better fit.

Comment: However, that's not the Michaelis-Menten model and thus, Kd does not have the usual interpretation.